# Getting rid off extra spaces using PHP. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: php, string

I am trying to retrieve some info from the site using PHP code below:

```
$doc = new domDocument();
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.ibar.az/en/');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$ExchangePart = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');
$USD=$ExchangePart->Item(91)->nodeValue;

$USD=htmlentities($USD);
$USD=str_replace("&nbsp","", $USD);

$TrimedUSD=trim($USD);

$USDArray=str_split($TrimedUSD);
$TotalSymbols=count($USDArray);
$k=0;

for ($i=0; $i<$TotalSymbols; $i++) {
    //var_dump($USDArray[$i]);
    if ($USDArray[$i]==" " or $USDArray[$i]==PHP_EOL) {
        $k=$k+1;
        //echo ($k."<br>");
            if ($k>1) {
                unset($USDArray[$i]);
            }
    } else {$k=0;}
}
var_dump($USDArray);
```

I am using for loop to get rid of extra spaces in the string. I deliberately do not want to use Regular Expressions.

Unfortunately the code cannot get rid off ALL EXTRA spaces.
The result of var_dump:

`array(34) { [0]=> string(1) "U" [1]=> string(1) "S" [2]=> string(1) "D" [3]=> string(1) " " [4]=> string(1) " " [5]=> string(1) " " [37]=> string(1) "1" [38]=> string(1) "." [39]=> string(1) "5" [40]=> string(1) "0" [41]=> string(1) "9" [42]=> string(1) "4" [43]=> string(1) " " [44]=> string(1) " " [45]=> string(1) " " [77]=> string(1) "1" [78]=> string(1) "." [79]=> string(1) "4" [80]=> string(1) "6" [81]=> string(1) "4" [82]=> string(1) "1" [83]=> string(1) " " [84]=> string(1) " " [85]=> string(1) " " [117]=> string(1) "1" [118]=> string(1) "." [119]=> string(1) "5" [120]=> string(1) "5" [121]=> string(1) "1" [122]=> string(1) "7" [123]=> string(1) " " [124]=> string(1) " " [125]=> string(1) " " [157]=> string(1) ";" }`

It leaves 3 spaces between words (array elements 4 &, 5), though I want to keep anly one space.

Could anybody suggest what I am doing wrong. Grasias! :)

UPDATE:

What I noticed when looked at the result of var_dump using Chrome view-source:

`array(34) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "U"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "S"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "D"
  [3]=>
  string(1) " "
  [4]=>
  string(1) ""
  [5]=>
  string(1) "
"
....
....`

See items [4] and [5]. I have feeling that these are NOT spaces... Any suggestion?

UPDATE 2

I used ORD function to convert and print every single symbol ASCII code:
`for ($i=0; $i<$TotalSymbols; $i++) {
    print_r(ord($USDArray[$i])."<br>");
}`

and discovered that the some of white spaces were only pretending white spaces :) Part of output:

85 - U
83 - S
68 - D
13 <- Carriage Return
10 <- Line Feed
32 - Ordinary Space
32 - Ordinary Space
...
...
...
Symbols with codes 10 & 13 are guilty!

Comment: Just a thought, maybe you can do something like: `if ($USDArray[$i]==" " && $USDArray[$i+1]==" ")` then do a second for loop that checks how "far" you have spaces, when you get that number you use a third for loop to unset from $i+1 to $i+$otherCounter. But why not use regex?

Comment: I just came to think about a thing. In the second counter you can unset the values. There is no point of the third for loop.

Comment: @Andreas - I want to solve this problem using PHP only

Comment: I was speaking PHP. Look at my answer below

Comment: Regex!!!! Is my suggestion

Comment: @Andreas - when I started learning web design I was going to use regex for web scrapping, but then I was advised to learn PHP and use it for web scrapping. I believe it is possible to solve the problem using PHP only. This what I am trying to do... :)

Comment: You are not using regex to parse html here, you are using regex to parse a string. Big difference. $TrimmedUSD is only letters and digits, correct? So there is no reason to not use regex. If you find regex not beeing php, then you shold not use any functions of php. You should develop your own functions and possibly code in binary.

Answer (score 1):

I think your trouble is with the `unset`, it makes the array skip elements.
You could try something like this:

```
$k=0;
$dummy_array = $USDArray;

foreach ($dummy_array as $key => $value) {
    //var_dump($USDArray[$i]);
    if ( " " == $value || $value == PHP_EOL || '' == $value) {
        $k=$k+1;
        //echo ($k."<br>");
            if ($k>1) {
                unset($USDArray[$key]);
            }
    } else {$k=0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($USDArray[$i]==" " && $USDArray[$i+1]==" "){ 
    $k = $i;
    While($USDArray[$k]==" ") {
        Unset($USDArray[$k]);
        $k++;
    }
    $i = $k+1;
}
```

Untested and written on my phone. So there could be some mistakes.

Comment: $i = $k+1; maybe should be only $i = $k as $i will increment in the for loop anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```
$USDArray = ['0' => 'A', '1' => 'B', '2' => ' ', '3' => ' ','4' => ' ', '5' => 'C','6' => ' ', '7' => ' '];
$USDArray = array_map('trim', $USDArray); // remove white space from array elements
for($i=0;$i<=count($USDArray);$i++){
    if (empty($USDArray[$i]) && empty($USDArray[$i+1])){        
          unset($USDArray[$i+1]);   
    }
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($USDArray);
```

OR

```
$USDArray = ['0' => 'A', '1' => 'B', '2' => ' ', '3' => ' ','4' => ' ', '5' => 'C','6' => ' ', '7' => ' '];
$USDArray = array_map('trim', $USDArray); // remove white space from array elements
foreach($USDArray as $k=>$v){
    if (empty($USDArray[$k]) && empty($USDArray[$k+1])){        
           unset($USDArray[$k+1]);   
    }
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($USDArray);
```

**output**:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => 
    [5] => C
    [6] => 
)
```

Note:- use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) it returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r(array_values($USDArray));
```

**output**:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => 
    [3] => C
    [4] => 
)
```

Comment: But the value is not empty, it's space. That is not the same?

Comment: @Andreas - Yes, you are right, `empty` and `space` is not the same

Comment: @Andreas:- Ohh!! thanks for pointing it out. I have just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only resonable thing is to use regex to do it.

```
$count = null;
$returnValue = preg_replace('/(\\s{2,})/', ' ', 'USD  11    99', -1, $count);


result: 'USD 11 99'
```